# Code coverage for COM API

Tags: c#, com, code-coverage

I am trying to get code coverage in VS 2017 Enterprise for some SpecFlow tests. The purpose of the tests are to connect to a COM service and use all of the exposed APIs.

When I run "Analyze Code Coverage", the results are only showing the lines and blocks covered where the SpecFlow statements correlate to my test code. What I want is at least what percent of the exposed API calls are being executed in the tests.

Is there a way to get this level of detail? The COM service is written in C++ while the tests are written in C#. Not sure if that really makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling COM from the .NET runtime, whether you realize it or not, you are using a [Runtime-Callable Wrapper (RCW)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/runtime-callable-wrapper).

There are a couple ways to [create an RCW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/interop/how-to-create-com-wrappers).  One way is to create it implicitly by adding a reference in visual studio. Another way is to [use Tlbimp.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/tlbimp-exe-type-library-importer) to create a .NET assembly that contains the wrapper. I suggest you use the latter method, and focus your code coverage statistics on the wrapper code.  If you achieve a high code coverage level on the wrapper, it means you are calling a high percentage of the underlying COM object's methods.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that.